# calculate division of fields dynamically using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, division

I'm "trying" to figure out how to calculate a division between to fields dynamically to display in another field, the thing is, all examples I've seen are sums, and those used something like this: `$('#field').each(function(){....});`.

I can't do that because there's no way of know which is the dividend and which is the divisor. I tried using "bind", to try to attach the function to the field. It didn't work.

Also tried putting "onChange="CalcularSaldo()" on the input field; no luck, but mainly because i'm pretty sure my function is wrong:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  function calcularSaldo() {
  var costo = document.getElementById("costo_ad").value;
  var vida = document.getElementById("vida_util").value; 
  document.getElementById("saldo_dep").value = costo / vida;
  }
  });</script>
```

Inputs:

```
  <label for="costo_ad">Costo de Adquisicion</label>
  <input name="costo_ad" type="text" id="costo_ad" class="round default-width-input" />

 <label for="vida_util">Vida Util</label>
 <input name="vida_util" type="text" id="vida_util" class="round default-width-input" />

 <label for="saldo_dep">Saldo a Depreciar</label>
 <input name="saldo_dep" type="text" id="saldo_dep" class="round default-width-input" disabled />
```

and the function should be something like this:

```
saldo_dep = costo_ad / vida_util
```

Comment: why is there "no way of know which is the dividend and which is the divisor"? Give them specific ids or classes to identify them.

Comment: ID's are unique x page, I'd go with Classes: `$('.field').each(function(){....});`

Comment: the way i see it, everytime someone uses "each" is because there's more than one, if there's more than one, how am i suppose to know which is which? see here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/sum-html-textbox-values-using-jquery-javascript/

Comment: Passed an string. It didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

suppose we have the following fields

```
<input type="number" id="field1">
<input type="number" id="field2">

<span id="label"></span>
```

so, you'd want to attach the jquery function to some action on the fields, like after the user finishes entering text in either of the boxes

```
$("#field1, #field2").keyup( function(){

     var n1 = $("#field1").val();
     var n2 = $("#field2").val();

     var result = n2/n1;
     $("#label").text(result);


});
```

Example is in jsFiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/A3qat/5/

Comment: `parseFloat($("field#').val());`